# a Href links in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, href

This is pretty straightforward.

I want to make a href link in html point to a site urls thats determined by a ruby variable.
So heres what I have:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
<% @tempJobUrl = job.url%>
<a href=<%=job.url%></a><%= job.url %>
```

job is an object which has the variable of url. The url is pretty standard format http://www.google.com and thats what shows up in the table. However when I press the link, it takes me to the page with

```
%3C/a
```

on the end.

Any ideas where this is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the helper method?

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= link_to job.url, job.url %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Im assuming you meant <%= link_to job.url,job.url%>   For some reason this wasnt working and was only taking me to the jobs display page. seems to have changed. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted it to be more similar to your HTML structure I wasn't aware of it will not work

Answer (score 2):

You should really use [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) Rails helper for this

Comment: I had already tried the link to like this  <%= link_to job.url%>  which just kept taking me back to the page i was already on.   the correct version is this <%= link_to job.url,job.url%>

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to use the helper method link_to in the following way:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= link_to job.url, job.url %>
<% end %>
```

The link_to helper is great for forming hyperlinks.  All you need to supply is the URL and the anchor text.  See the Ruby on Rails [documentation for link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Felix said, use the link_to helper

```
<% @somevar = job.url %>
<%= link_to "Anchor text", @somevar %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "#{@data[:item_name]}", @data[:link] %>
```

If you need a hyperlink where you need the name of item along with link, you can do something similar to this.

```
<%= link_to "Task", Task_Link %>
```